# IIS ASP.NET Impersonation: specific user specified but User.Identity is blank

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, impersonation

The application works well (meaning, `User.Identity.Name` is properly identified) when:

- Anonymous Authentication is Disabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation is Enabled, and set to use Authenticated User
- Windows Authentication is Enabled

Now, the user will be accessing it outside the domain, and should not be required to enter his login/password but still be authenticated.
So, I simply did the following:

- Anonymous Authentication Enabled
- Set ASP.NET Impersonation to this user domain name and password
- Windows Authentication is Disabled (although it would not make a difference in this case)

The application is loading, but `User.Identity.Name` is black and I expected it to have the user specified in the ASP.NET Impersonation. I need this `User.Identity.Name` to be a valid user because it's used later inside the app.

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

By design "anonymous" means that you don't know who is connected.User.Identity.The name might be empty if Anonymous Authentication is enabled in IIS.

you can use the below code to check if the identity is available.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
else
    Label1.Text = "No user identity available.";
```

You could also use  "[profile migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ewfkf772(v=vs.100))".

Comment: Thank you, but I specified which user to impersonate. I also set the same user in the Connect As in the IIIS website basic configuration.

Comment: in this situation, you could use the form authentication. [link1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/308157/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio) [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/using-aspnet-forms-authentication)